# Exception: Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x4

Tags: android, imageview

I need to enlarge image I am using the following code for it

```
  int imageId =  (Integer) intent.getExtras().get(ProfilePageNormalUser.class.getName());
  imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageviewEnlarged);
  System.out.println("*********"+imageId);

  InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(imageId);
  Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
  Matrix imageMatrix = new Matrix(); imageMatrix.postRotate(90);
  Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(originalBitmap, imageView.getWidth(), imageView.getHeight(), originalBitmap.getWidth(), originalBitmap.getHeight(), imageMatrix, false);
  imageView.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
```

But is giving me the above exception .

```
         Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x4
```

Can anyone tell me where could be the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think to use `this.getResources().openRawResource(id)`. You'll have to move your resource to res/raw folder.

Try creating a folder named raw under res folder and paste your resource there.

Let me know how it goes..

Answer (score 0):

`OpenRawResource` couldn't find the resouce from `imageId` that you are using.

Check your imageId.

You can use directly: I think : `InputStream ins = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.my_db_file);`

the specify imageId like mentioned above from raw folder.

Check first like this , it works or not.

Comment: I set the imageid explicitly in the last activity  and getting the same imageid in this activity